# fill in gaps while merging data in python

Tags: python, csv, matrix, gaps-and-islands

here is my problem:
I'm starting from several matrices to which extract data to build a new and general matrix.
The first step is to read the infiles with csv module and extract "position" values (stored in row[1]) that will be used as columns headers in the final matrix. Each infile contains a subset of the total "positions", which sometimes are present in more tha one infile. So I am first of all building an ordered list (from smaller to bigger integer) from the merging of all "position" values, ignoring the repeated ones.This is how I am doing it:

```
for infile in glob.glob('passed_*.vcf'):
    infilen=open(infile)
    inf = csv.reader(infilen,delimiter='\t')
    for row in inf:
        if row[1] in pos:
            continue
        else:
            pos.append(row[1])
    infilen.close()
pos.sort(key=int)
head=str('\t'.join(pos))
of=open('trial.txt', 'a')   
print>>of,head
```

Once done that, I go back to the original infiles and read for another value (in row[3] this time) which I want to add under the corrisponding header created above (i.e. "position"). Since each infile bears a subset of the total positions, I'll have to fill the gaps when the final matrix position (stored in list "pos") is not present in row[1] of the individual infile.
Here the code I'm trying:

```
for infile in glob.glob('passed_*.vcf'):
    infilen=open(infile)
    inf = csv.reader(infilen,delimiter='\t')
    seq=[]
    for row in inf:
        if row[1] in pos:
            seq.append(row[3])  
        else:
            seq.append('N')
```

Needless to say, I'm stuck. I was thinking to use a while loop, but since I'm not really experienced, I'm asking you an advice of any sort.

### sample data

input (sample 1):

```
1   2025    blah    A   .   blah    PASS    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
2   2027    blah    C   .   blah    blah    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
3   2028    blah    T   .   blah    PASS    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
```

input (sample n):

```
1   2025    blah    G   .   blah    PASS    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
2   2026    blah    A   .   blah    blah    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
3   3089    blah    T   .   blah    PASS    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
```

output (single matrix with input row[1] as variables and row[3] as values. each row is a different sample, i.e. a different input file):

```
          2025    2026    2027    2028  ...  3089
sample1    A       NaN     C       T         NaN
samplen    G        A     NaN     NaN         T
```

Comment: You probably want to use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) to load, merge and dice and slice your matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about that - but since I came at this point (which, trust me, for my python skills is really exiting), I was looking for an "indipendent" way to complete my code.

Comment: Can you please add short examples (at least 2 vcf samples, and desired output) ? It'll make much easier to figure out what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import glob
>>> pos = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for index, infile in enumerate(glob.glob('D:\\DATA\\FP12210\\My Documents\\Temp\\Python\\sample*.vcf'), 1):
    for line in open(infile):
        # Convert value in integer already
        val, letter = int(line.split()[1]), line.split()[3]
        pos[val][index] = letter


>>> def print_pos(pos):
    """ Formats pos """
    # Print header by sorting keys of pos
    values = sorted(pos.keys())
    print '          ',
    for val in range(values[0], values[-1] + 1):
        print '{0:5}'.format(val),
    print

    # pos has keys according to row1, create pos2 with keys = sample #
    pos2 = defaultdict(dict)
    for val, d in pos.iteritems():
        for index, letter in d.iteritems():
            pos2[index][val] = letter

    # Now easier to print lines
    for index in sorted(pos2.keys()):
        print ' sample{0:2} '.format(index),
        for val in range(values[0], values[-1] + 1):
            if val in pos2[index]:
                print '   {0} '.format(pos2[index][val]),
            else:
                print ' NaN ',
        print


>>> print_pos(pos)
            2025  2026  2027  2028  2029  2030  2031  2032
 sample 1     A   NaN     C     T   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 
 sample 2     G     A   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     T 
>>>
```

I use `pos` to collect values, I also use `pos2` which contains the same data ordered differently for print purpose because:

- `pos` is value-oriented, useful to have range of values
- `pos2` is sample-oriented, useful to have values given a sample number

Not to have a range too big, I used values:

-sample1.vcf:

```
1   2025    blah    A   .   blah    PASS    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
2   2027    blah    C   .   blah    blah    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
3   2028    blah    T   .   blah    PASS    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
```

-sample2.vcf:

```
1   2025    blah    G   .   blah    PASS    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
2   2026    blah    A   .   blah    blah    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
3   2032    blah    T   .   blah    PASS    AC=0    GT:DP   0/0:61
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, I didn't think of the dictionary approach before. I'll test this solution with the huge amount of data I'm dealing with.